# Timed button press

Tags: c++, timer, keypress, formula

I was playing a racing game and after a while I started thinking how the gear shifting mechanism was implemented. I'm trying to do something similar, but much more simple. In this program I am printing out the number 128. as time goes on the number decreases. If I press a key at 4 secs the number should revert back to 128 and start decreasing again. My main issue is finding a way to calculate the multiplier as you see below. As you can see What I'm currently doing does not work. After 800 miliseconds the resulting value increases again and goes past 1. I want the max value at 1 so that when i press a button at 4 seconds the multiplier is 1 to get exactly 128. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
start timer
loop after this point
    get time to variable
    if button press
       multiplier=1-(abs(time-400)/400)
       clear timer
       get time to variable
    print (128*multiplier)*(100/(time+100))
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start timer
loop after this point
    get time to variable
    if button press
       multiplier=1-(abs(time-400)/400)
       if multiplier < 0
           multiplier = 0
       clear timer
       get time to variable
    print (128*multiplier)*(100/(time+100))
```